# trying to enable php_fileinfo extension

Tags: laravel, cpanel, shared-hosting, laravel-6

i uploaded a laravel project on shared hosting -ssh not available- i configured it

the front-end worked successfully, registration entries didn't work and got this error "

Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enable the php_fileinfo extension?).

"

and i searched on internet and i changed to

[image: added extension=php_fileinfo.dll]

[image: checked fileinfo]

and the problem still happening

where is the problem

Comment: For changes to take effect, you may have to restart PHP. Do you have this option available?

Comment: unfortunately no